# Of what use is the directional derivative when the one with the maximum norm is the gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

With all due respects, I am missing the intuition of the directional derivative. Other than confusing the situation I see no purpose.  The directional derivative with the maximum norm is the gradient. BUT it can be no other way since the gradient is the slope at that point. The slope in the direction of that each particular gradient at that point is by definition the slope for that function.  This means the function at the point has that slope! any steeper or more shallow would not only not be on the surface level it would not even be a solution. to the function. I am OK with the gradient but can see no utility of the directional derivative.  I can certainly see the intuition and purpose of the gradient field but no purpose to directional derivative field, in fact  there may not even be a definition of a directional derivative field.

Comment: Are you claiming that partial derivatives should not be defined?

Comment: Well, we'll have to abolish the notion, if you don't find it intuitive, I'm afraid. We're lucky most don't question the intuition of $1+1=2$, and are generously tolerant with potentiation, even though +-*/ is sufficient and more intuitive.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the slope of the function".  If you are standing on a hill, what is the slope?  there are, presumably, directions you can walk in that go neither up nor down.  Not every walk on a hill is maximally up or down!  Would you not agree that it is, say, interesting to know the directions of zero climb?

Comment: Ah Thomas Klimpel.....was kind enough to show me the utility.  Very good ,answer accepted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of the directional derivative is that it generalizes to many different situations where the gradient may not exist or may not even be defined. This can sometimes give nice insights.

For a function $f$ on a finite dimensional space, we have the following theorem:

> If the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ exists and is linear in the direction, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ iff the chain rule holds at $x$.

For deeper insights, it is often required to first generalize the directional derivative from the case where the direction is constant to the case where the direction is given by a vector field. Let us call this generalized directional derivative the *Lie derivative*. We may then notice that the Lie derivative of a function by a vector field transforms canonically. The Lie derivative of a function by a vector field is again a function. We can then generalize the Lie derivative further to also allow differentiation of vector fields and differential forms by a vector field, such that the Lie derivative transforms canonically. This gives us the Poisson brackets of vector fields for the derivative of a vector field by another vector field, and the divergence of a vector field for the Lie derivative of the canonical volume form by a vector field (divided by the canonical volume form).

A long time ago, I wrote a [German text](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6x6GQ82vuH_YnE2STNKZXU1cUk) that investigated connections between the directional derivative and other notions in differential geometry like differentiability or Poisson brackets. Actually, the topic was rather the use of test curves, test functions and the canonical straightening of a vector field as proof techniques, but the above connections are also explained there.

Comment: Many thanx   ...very interesting ...if you know any applications of this in the study of physics please don't hesitate to drop a comment....I am using the gradient to help with Maxwell's Equations.....

Comment: @Sedumjoy The use of test function can be useful to avoid unnecessary calculations in coordinates. If you study physics, you should have come across situations already were even physicists prefer that strategy. (Thinking of it now, they only seem to switch when it is more or less unavoidable.) The test curves are most useful for clarifying consequences of minor details in mathematical definitions. I know no useful physical application of them. But the canonical straightening (related to transformation behavior and directional derivatives) is helpful for understanding many phenomena in physics.